# System time is wrong in Proxmox VE host, how can I fix it?

Tags: debian, virtualization, time, ntp, timezone

I'm using the latest version of Proxmox VE (which is based on Debian) and I can't fix the wrong time problem:

```
$ pveversion -v
pve-manager: 1.7-11 (pve-manager/1.7/5470)
running kernel: 2.6.32-4-pve
proxmox-ve-2.6.32: 1.7-30
pve-kernel-2.6.32-4-pve: 2.6.32-30
qemu-server: 1.1-28
pve-firmware: 1.0-10
libpve-storage-perl: 1.0-16
vncterm: 0.9-2
vzctl: 3.0.24-1pve4
vzdump: 1.2-10
vzprocps: 2.0.11-1dso2
vzquota: 3.0.11-1
pve-qemu-kvm: 0.13.0-3
ksm-control-daemon: 1.0-4
```

The host system's time is:

```
$ date
Fri Feb 25 12:39:12 CET 2011
```

but this is wrong because the correct time should be

```
Fri Feb 25 11:39:12 CET 2011
```

Because that's the local time in Belgium (where that server is located).

The timezone of the proxmox host is:

```
$ cat /etc/timezone 
Europe/Brussels
```

And there was no timezone setting in the server's BIOS settings. **The server's BIOS screen shows the time correctly**. I also receive the following warning from the system:

```
warning: `ntpd' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
```

According to /etc/default/rcS:

```
TMPTIME=0
SULOGIN=no
DELAYLOGIN=no
UTC=no
VERBOSE=no
FSCKFIX=no
RAMRUN=no
RAMLOCK=no
```

(Previously it was UTC=yes and I changed it into UTC=no and rebooted the server, hoping it would help but nothing changed.)

The ntp daemon is running and I did not make any changes to any ntp configuration file, they are at proxmox defaults.

How can I fix this wrong time issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does

```
/usr/sbin/ntpq -p
```

show?

Try doing

```
sntp -P no -r pool.ntp.org
```

to set the time right and do afterwards a

```
hwclock --systohc
```

to write the time to the hardware clock.

Comment: $ ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 ns.ttosi.net    .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 79.99.122.30    .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 xen02.cblue.be  .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 ns2.ttosi.net   .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000

Comment: I had to install msntp package because I could not find anything starting with sntp. Anyway running msntp -P no -r pool.ntp.org just led to a long long wait so I had to Ctrl-c it. On the other hand when I did dpkg-reconfigure tzdata and then selected None of the above and then UTC it started to show the correct time. However I don't know if this is the right thing to do, e.g. changing the timezone from Europe/Brussels to Etc/UTC. On other Linux systems I used (mostly Ubuntu) I set the timezone according to the geographical location and did not encounter any problems. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: Apparently the NTP port 123 was blocked on the firewall, the problem is solved after port 123 is opened. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: `no such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

**Setting the time manually**:

In-case anyone's system is air-gapped, one can set the time manually...

From [here](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/proxmox-time-set-manually-host.70966/) one of the ProxMox staff suggested to perform a [regular Debian config](https://wiki.debian.org/DateTime):

> ```
>  date --set 1998-11-02
>  date --set 21:08:00
>  hwclock --systohc
> ```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is configure a public NTP server (following  https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Time_Synchronization).

Based on what is written in `/etc/chrony/conf.d/README` and `/etc/chrony/sources.d/README`, I just had to run:

```
echo 'server ntp.adelaide.edu.au iburst' > /etc/chrony/sources.d/ntp-server.sources
chronyc reload sources
```

(pick a public NTP server close to your location)

You can check if it worked by checking the logs:

```
journalctl -u chrony | tail
```